# No se introducen registros con decimales en la Base de Datos

Tags: c#

tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar a  ver si vosotros tenéis la respuesta

Tengo un fragmento de código que multiplica unas horas de manera decimal. Ese mismo resultado lo muestro mediante un `MessageBox.Show` y se muestra el número con sus decimales (Hasta aquí todo perfecto). El problema lo tengo que después de mostrar el número mediante el `MessageBox` se introduce en la base de datos hecha en ACCESS sin decimales, es decir.... si por ejemplo la multiplicación su resultado es `1230,50` en el `MessageBox` se muestra `1230,50` pero en la base de datos queda registrado el numero `123050`.

En la tabla access la columna encargada de registrar los datos esta como número general, tengo varias columnas con el mismo tipo de columna y registran los datos con decimal perfectamente.

Código:

```
 for (int c = 0; c <= maxRegistrosO - 1; c++)
            {
                EditH = dataSet5.Tables["Operarias"].Rows[c];

                if ((int)EditH["Id"] == valorEnForm2H)
                {

                    decimal PrecioHoras = (decimal)EditH["PrecioHoras"];
                    decimal Sueldo = ((decimal)PrecioHoras * (decimal)NuevasHoras);

                    //MessageBox.Show(Sueldo.ToString());

                    conexion.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();



                    int i= 0;

                    cmd.Connection = conexion;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Horas", NuevasHoras);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sueldo", Sueldo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", valorEnForm2H);




                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Operarias SET Horas = @Horas, Sueldo = @Sueldo WHERE Id = @Id";


                    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Guardado");
                    conexion.Close();
                    this.Close();
                    fomularioAActualizarH.MostrarTablaOperarias();
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla de access? Editá tu pregunta y añadí ese dato, es importante!

Comment: Revisa el formato de los decimales de Access. Hay ocasiones en las que las BBDD para reconocer un número como decimal requieren de un punto en vez de una coma. También revisa que la columna es de tipo decimal o doble, no entero. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El error parece a primera vista un error del **Data Type** definido en la Base de Datos, es correcto lo que estas haciendo de guardar la variable como decimal.

Te recomiendo también cambiar:

```
decimal Sueldo = ((decimal)PrecioHoras * (decimal)NuevasHoras);
```

por:

```
decimal Sueldo = (decimal)(PrecioHoras * NuevasHoras);
```

Comment: La expresión me parece que no es correcta, el error que me salta es :El operador '*' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'decimal' y 'double'

Comment: Pensé que las dos eran del mismo Tipo, bien entonces solamente necesitas castear *NuevasHoras* ya que PrecioHoras ya es del Tipo decimal. Si sigue sin funcionar como te puse en la respuesta, revisa el Data Type definido en tu BD, no tengo muy en claro la definición necesaria de las variables en Access pero te dejo a disposición los tipos de datos a definir en Access: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15